# Inserting HTML as text in mysql database

Tags: mysql, node.js

I am trying to insert `HTML` as text in mysql database using Node JS. But due to some reasons there's an error, which says :

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '`company_jobs_details` VALUES (null, 'none', ''

I don't know what is the problem. I converted the HTML to string first using `html.toString()` and then `mysql.escape(html)` in order to put the slashes, but the problem is still the same :

Below is my HTML :

```js
< h1 > < span style = "font-size:14.0px" > Liebherr in the USA < /span></h
1 >

  <
  h1 > < span style = "font-size:14.0px" > In line with its international growth, Liebherr’ s venture into the United States began in 1970. Within a couple of years, the company expanded and completed its production facilities in Newport News, VA
for its product line of hydraulic excavators.It was later converted into Liebherr’ s manufacturing facility
for mining trucks and remains home to Liebherr Mining Equipment Newport News, Co. & nbsp;
In addition to its production facility, Liebherr markets a wide variety of products and technologies through its companies located across the United States.The companies are Liebherr - Aerospace Saline, Inc., Liebherr Gear Technology, Inc., Liebherr Automation Systems, Co., and Liebherr USA, Co., the umbrella company
for eight divisions that are positioned across the United States. < /span></h
1 >

  <
  p > & nbsp; < /p> <
p > The Technical Writer develops, writes and edits material
for reports, instructions and operating, service, maintenance, and repair manuals and related technical and administrative publications concerning the work methods, procedures, installations, operations, repairs and maintenance of components, assemblies and complete machines. & nbsp; < /p>

<
p > & nbsp; < /p>

<
p > < strong > Responsibilities: < /strong></p >

  <
  ul >
  <
  li > Assists senior technical writer with department technical writing and content administrative duties. < /li> <
  li > Assists with preparing reports, briefs, proposals, instructions and related technical and administrative materials
for publishing. < /li> <
  li > Assists with the development of work methods, procedures and installation, operation, repair and maintenance procedures. < /li> <
  li > Observes production, assembly and development to determine operating, maintaining and repair procedures and details. < /li> <
  li > Collaborates with SME, production, engineering and service personnel, read journals, reports and other materials to become familiar with product and production methods. < /li> <
  li > Gathers and researches information to procure documentation
for various manual outputs. < /li> <
  li > Develops material
for the end user that is clear, concise and easy to understand. < /li> <
  li > Reviews manufacturer’ s and trade catalogs, drawings and other data relative to operation, maintenance, repair and service of components and equipment. < /li> <
  li > Organizes material and complete writing assignment according to set standards regarding order, clarity, conciseness, style and terminology. < /li> <
  li > Maintains records and files of work and revision history. < /li> <
  li > Edits, standardize, or make changes to material prepared by other writers, service or engineering personnel. < /li> <
  li > Consults with technical team leads, engineering, service technicians and other subject matter experts to ensure common understanding of publications and related materials to be generated. < /li> <
  li > Assists in maintaining cataloging systems, records, files, electronic media and archiving of information
for publications
for business references. < /li> <
  li > Uploads manuals and technical information to the content delivery portal. < /li> <
  li > Receives translated files from translation vendor and creates alternate language manuals based on truck commissioning schedules. < /li> <
  li > Reviews of published material, revision changes, format, and content accuracy. < /li> <
  li > Assists in preparing material
for technical seminars and business forums. < /li> <
  li > Assists in maintaining content changes and updates to publications.. < /li> <
  /ul>

  <
  p > & nbsp; < /p>

<
p > < strong > Competencies: < /strong></p >

  <
  ul >
  <
  li > Associate’ s degree(A.A.S.) in communications and publications, and a minimum of two(2) years of practical experience;
or a Technical degree from an accredited institution in a related field and at least four(4) or more years of experience, or equivalent combination of education and experience. < /li> <
  li > Applies the required Knowledge, Skills, and Abilities(KSA) in the performance of essential job duties: < /li> <
  li > Skilled in grammar, technical writing and editing skills. < /li> <
  li > Skilled in word processing, spreadsheets, electronic authoring, and database management software. < /li> <
  li > Knowledge and understanding of Simplified English. < /li> <
  li > Knowledge of XTML, HTML & amp;
XML authoring, and graphics
for various media publications, i.e.web - based publishing. < /li> <
  li > Knowledge of ERP System as it relates to truck Bill of Material(BOM) structure. < /li> <
  li > Working knowledge of Arbortext Editor(XML authoring) and Acrobat Pro. < /li> <
  li > Ability to use Microsoft Office and utilities. < /li> <
  li > Ability to interpret complex instructions into clear, concise directions. < /li> <
  li > Ability to write routine reports and correspondence. < /li> <
  li > Ability to deal with problems involving several concrete variables in standardized situations. < /li> <
  li > Ability to define problems, collect data, establish facts and draw valid conclusions. < /li> <
  /ul>

  <
  p style = "margin-left:40.0px" > < strong > Additional Requirements: < /strong></p >

  <
  ul >
  <
  li > Expected to travel nationally and internationally up to 20 % to customer or supplier sites. < /li> <
  li > Ability to obtain and maintain mine certifications or safety training such as Mine Safety and Health Administration(MSHA) hazard training. < /li> <
  li > Ability to obtain and maintain a valid driver’ s license and passport. < /li> <
  /ul>

  <
  p > & nbsp; < /p>

<
p > < strong > Our Offer: < /strong></p >

  <
  p > An interesting and ambitious role in a successful international company.We offer a secure work environment with a comprehensive benefits package that includes major medical, dental and vision insurance, 401 K plan with company match, paid vacation and personal days and competitive salary. & nbsp; < /p>

<
p > Applications are only accepted via the online - portal & nbsp; < a href = "http://www.liebherr.com/" > www.liebherr.com < /a>.</p >
```

**My SQL query**

```js
this.saveJobsDetails = async function(details) {
  customConsole("Database", "Saving Jobs Details to the database, please wait...");

  ms_connect.query("INSERT INTP `company_jobs_details` VALUES (null, 'none', '" + mysql.escape(details) + "', " + (count + 1) + ", " + (job_number + 1) + ")", function(err, row) {
    if (err) {
      throw err;
    } else {
      customConsole("Database", "Details for Job # <span class='b'>" + (job_number + 1) + "</span> have been saved successfully...");
      console.log("Details Entered !");
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: You have a typo in the query. `INSERT INTP company_jobs_details` should be `INSERT INTO company_jobs_details`

Comment: @JoshuaTerrill yeah, and actually I removed that. But solved by `mysql.escape()`